# Mantenerse en un "div" al enviar datos de formulario

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, div

Me estoy iniciando en el mundo php y mysql. Os comento mi escenario, a ver si me podéis echar un cable:

Tengo un archivo "index.php" que conecta con una BD en phpMyadmin, en la que existen diferentes tablas. En el archivo "index.php", tengo apuntando a otro ".php" para la conexión  a la BD y todo OK.

Aquí viene la duda: el archivo principal (index.php) tengo diferentes "divs", para mostrar:

```
<div id="op1">INICIO</div> //Con su correspondiente contenido...
<div id="op2">Registro</div> //Formulario para ingresar en las tablas...
<div id="op3">Listado</div> //Tabla que me muestra una consulta de todos los registros...
<div id="op4">xxxxxx</div>....
```

Tengo un menu horizontal, donde cada botón me muestra un div y esconde los demás, hecho con funciones de Javascript.

Cuando creo un registro desde el div "op2", cuando termina el envío se me pasa al div "op1" y no se mantiene en el mismo div de Registro para meter mas datos, y tengo que irme al menu de botones para volver al formulario.

¿Qué tengo que poner en el "action" del formulario para que se mantenga en el mismo "div"?

Lo tengo así:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" name="Form">
```

Aparte me surge otro problema, que si actualizo el navegador, me sale una alerta de Chrome que va a reenviar los datos del formulario y por consiguiente me duplica la entrada en la base de datos.

¿Cómo podría solucionar estos detalles?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El  action del formulario vuelve a llamar a la misma página, PHP comprueba habitualmente que se ha pulsado un botón submit o similar y procesa los datos del formulario, (aquí podría activar el botón Registro). Si no,  pues muestra el formulario para rellenarlo. Esto es el comportamiento típico. Como no pones él código de la pagina no se puede decir mucho más.

Comment: Qué código necesitas ver para ayudarme, el archivo index.php?

Comment: Hola @Miwe, ¿eres Miguel el de la pregunta?

Comment: si soy el mismo. Es que hice la pregunta como invitado y despues he iniciado sesión.

Comment: @Miwe completa el [tour] y no uses las respuestas para dejar comentarios. Creo que las cuentas se deberían fusionar si son la misma persona.